# Ajax:success not working in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, json, turbolinks

Within a rails 4 app, I am using a link_to to send an upvote on posts via json.

Here is what I have in my posts controller:

```
def upvote
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.liked_by current_user

    respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to :back }
    format.json { render json: { count: @post.get_upvotes.size } }
  end
end
```

Here is what I have in my view

```
<%= link_to like_post_path(post), method: :put, class: 'vote', remote: true, data: { type: :json } do %>
    <%= image_tag('vote.png') %>
    <%= content_tag :span, post.get_upvotes.size %>
    <% end %>


    <script>

    $(document)
        .on('ajax:send', '.vote', function () { $(this).addClass('loading'); })
        .on('ajax:complete', '.vote', function () { $(this).removeClass('loading'); })
        .on('ajax:error', '.vote', function(e, xhr, status, error) { console.log(status); console.log(error); })
        .on('ajax:success', '.vote', function (e, data, status, xhr) {
        $(this).find("span").html(data.count);
        $(this).find("img").attr("src", '<%= asset_path 'voted.png' %>'); 
        });


    </script>
```

When I click on the link, the vote goes through as a JSON request, I see this in my log:

```
Processing by PostsController#upvote as JSON
```

But for some reason, my snipped of javascript is not working. Neither the counter or the icon update. **How can I fix this? Does this have to do with turbolinks, does it have to do with where I am placing the javascript?**

Comment: Is the javascript executing at all (out a breakpoint or some calls to console.log in there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails you can perform a similar task by having a JavaScript response. Add in your `respond_to` a `format.js` similar to `format.html` then have a view `upvote.js.erb` that looks like:

```
(function() {    

var postId = "#post-<%= @post.id %>";

$(postId).find(".vote").find("span").text("<%= @post.get_upvotes.size %>");
$(postId).find(".vote").find("img").attr("src", "<%= asset_path "voted.png" %>");

})();
```

I changed your call to `.html` to `.text` since you're not actually setting any HTML inside the element, there is no reason to call `.html`.

This post also assumes there is some mechanism to identify the post the vote link belongs to (in the example the parent post element has an ID of "post-#" where # is the ID of the post object).

**EDIT**

Two changes I'd make if I were working on this project. First I would attach the `voted.png` path to the `.vote` element as a data attribute. `data-voted-image-src="<%= asset_path "voted.png" %>"`. Next, I would never pass a number in the return as there is no reason to do so. When the vote is clicked you can handle everything on the front end by assuming the request is successful. Which saves all this potential nastiness. While I realize that changing from what you current have to adding the data attribute isn't a huge leap I just find it more semantic than having it in the JavaScript.

The click action on the vote link then becomes:

```
// Assume all posts have a class 'post'
// I'm also using 'one' because once they vote they don't need to anymore
$(".post").find(".vote").one("click", function(e) {
  var count = parseInt($(this).find("span").text()),
      votedSrc = $(this).data("voted-image-src");
  $(this).find("img").attr("src", votedSrc);
  $(this).find("span").text(count + 1);
});
```

Now no response from the server is necessary, and you can change your JSON response to `{success: true}` or something simple.

Comment: *When the vote is clicked you can handle everything on the front end by assuming the request is successful.*  Then it's possible to have a mismatch between what is displayed on the page and what the server's tally is.  If the request fails, the server won't update the vote count, yet the page will increment the vote count.

Comment: Yes. It is possible. As it is possible by doing it any other way. There is no way to keep the client 100% in sync  the only guarantee is that when you request the page the data is accurate as of time and machine rendered. If you have a SPA then you need more consistent methods for accuracy anyway like web sockets or long polling to keep those numbers in place but even with long polling I'd still assume the response was a success and let the long poll result correct any discrepancies.

Comment: @Brandon Buck: Am I missing something here, but I think it defeats the purpose of the client-server model. I mean, if the server sends a successful response one should update the client accordingly only then.

Comment: @hajder Actually it's not uncommon to presume a request is successful. If the request then fails, by all means update the UI (remove the votes in question) and provide some details to the client. This gives the client the feeling that your application is responsive to their actions (most of the time, requests should be successful - therefore: the user clicks, you assume success and update the UI, the request is successful, no further changes are required. They see an update once, immediately when the click. Instead of the inherent delay waiting for your server to respond.

Comment: @hajder As a side note to that thought though, this doesn't work with all scenarios. Certain actions do require a response (such as login/registering) before you should move on, but simple UI components are perfect places to provide this small boost for your users.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery` is the default rails javascript library.  The default rails javascript library used to be `prototype`, so old tutorials/docs use it.  This is what the ajax looks like with jQuery:

app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def show_link
  end

  def upvote
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render json: {"count" => "10"} }
    end
  end

end
```

app/views/static_pages/show_link.html:

```
<div>Here is an ajax link:</div>

<%= link_to(
    "Click me", 
    '/static_pages/upvote', 
    'remote' => true,  #Submit request with ajax, and put text/javascript on front of Accept header
    data: { type: :json })  #Put application/json on front of Accept header
%>


<div>Upvotes:</div>
<div id="upvotes">3</div>

<script>
$(document).ready( function() {

  $(this).ajaxSuccess( function(event, jqXHR, ajaxInfo, data) {

    //var js_obj = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
    //$('#upvotes').html(js_obj["count"]);

    //Apparently, the fourth argument to the handler, data,
    //already contains the js_obj created from parsing the  
    //json string contained in the response. 

    $('#upvotes').html(data["count"]);
  });

}); 
</script>
```

config/routes.rb:

```
Test1::Application.routes.draw do

  get 'static_pages/show_link'
  get 'static_pages/upvote'
  ...
end
```

url to enter in browser:

```
http://localhost:3000/static_pages/show_link
```

See jquery docs here:

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/

**Response to comment:**

You could also do the following in your controller:

```
  def upvote

    @upvotes = 2  #Set an @variable to the number of upvotes

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {}  #By default renders app/views/static_pages/upvote.js.erb
    end

  end
```

Then:

app/views/static_pages/upvote.js.erb:

```
$('#upvotes').html(<%= @upvotes %>)
```

Comment: This is rails, why not use a JavaScript response?